# Get data from file using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to do this scenario .
If folder is empty then return false else return true .
To do that i tried this

```
function downloadExcel() {
// Mu folder path 
var folder="D:/output";
if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'check_file.php',
                    data: {
                        folder: folder
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                        if(result==false)
                        {
                            Swal.fire(
                                    'execution success '
                            );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Swal.fire(
                                'extraction failed '
                            );  
                        }
                        
                },
                error: function(result){

                   console.log("Error request Ajax");
                } 
                });
                
                refresh();

            } else if (
                result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
```

my php file to render the data :: **check_file.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["folder"])) {
$dir = $_POST['folder'];
}

if (is_dir_empty($dir)) {
echo "the folder is empty"; 
$result=false;

}else{
 echo "the folder is NOT empty";
 $result=true; 
}

return $result;


function is_dir_empty($dir) {
if (!is_readable($dir)) return null; 
return (count(scandir($dir)) == 2);
}

?>
```

When i run my check_file.php the check if directory is empty or not works fine .

But when i try the the **$result variable** there something gone wrong about my code

The $result variable is always empty

Comment: `return` command work only in functions. so change it to `echo $result;`

Comment: Everything you echo in PHP will be part of the response in your JS (which means that `result==false` will never be true (since you always echo a message). You also can't use `return $result` in that context. That won't do anything other than aborting the script.

Comment: Also keep in mind that doing `echo false` will yield an empty string. You are better off with echo'ing `1` or `0` if you want to use the result in JS

Comment: If you want to get a boolean state back, either just echo `1` for success and `0` for fail and check that in your JS instead (since you won't get what you assume when echoing booleans). An alternative (which I recommend) is to return JSON instead with a `success` attribute: `{success: true/false, message: "some custom message if needed"}` and use that object in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're never echoing `$result` - and even if you did, echoing a boolean `false` doesn't actually produce any visible output. Using `return` to end the main part of a script isn't necessary, doesn't really make much sense and certainly doesn't produce any output.
2. The things you *are* echoing consist of neither `true` nor `false`, so obviously the JS code won't match those either.
3. To allow the JS to detect a truth-y or false-y value accurately, it's better to output numeric `0` or `1` than strings.
4. As an additional point, it would make sense not to try and use `$dir` unless it's been populated.

This version should help you (note that if there's no value in `$_POST["folder"]` it won't output *anything* - you might want to add something extra to deal with that, but I'll leave it up to you):

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["folder"])) 
{
  $dir = $_POST['folder'];
  $result;

  if (is_dir_empty($dir)) $result = 0; 
  else $result = 1;

  echo $result;
}

function is_dir_empty($dir) {
  if (!is_readable($dir)) return null; 
  return (count(scandir($dir)) == 2);
}
?>
```